# Symfony3 Form class Entity Manager

Tags: forms, class, entitymanager, symfony

I have trouble with migration to Symfony3.
I have a form in FormType class and I pass Entity manager throught constructor.

Here is example of code:
Controller

```
$form = $this->createForm(new SubjectType($emDefault));
```

Form Class

```
class SubjectType extends AbstractType {
    private $em;
    public function __construct($em) {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {        
        $builder
                ->add('subject', 'entity', array(
                    'em' => $this->em,
                    'class' => 'MyBundle:Subject',
                    'query_builder' => function ($em) {
                        return $em->createQueryBuilder('s')
                        ->where('s.active = 1');
                    },
                    'property' => 'name')
                )
                ->add('create', 'submit', array('label' => 'choose'));
    }
    ...
```

Symfony 3 has change in method createForm to:

```
$this->createForm(SubjectType::class);
```

And with this declaration, I don't know how to pass entity manager to form class.

Anyone help, please?

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your FormType [as a service.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html#creating-your-field-type-as-a-service)

**services.yml**

```
services:
    app.form.type.subject:
        class: AppBundle\Form\Type\SubjectType
        arguments: ["@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"]
        tags:
            - { name: form.type }
```

Re-add the commented line in your constructor and you'll be able to use `$this->em` as in previous versions.

Comment: Thank you. I found this earlier in documentation but I had some other errors in my code, so this solutions doesn't work for me, but now I used it and it is 
But now it finally works :)

Comment: If you want, create another question with your error trace, I'll be glad to debug with you.